# Do Azure Logic Apps have a built-in way to chunk up arrays of data for batch processing

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that (among other, not relevant things) calls API A to fetch data (as a JSON array), and sends that data to API B.

B handles data uploads in batches that are smaller than the size of the data set that A returns, so in order to submit them, I must chunk up the data from A into smaller arrays and submit multiple batches to B.

I have not found any Logic App actions that look like they would do the job, but it is quite possible that I missed something. There is the `foreach` action, which is probably what I want to use *after* the data is chunked up, but I definitely do not want to be submitting these one-by-one.

Preliminarily, I think I can get the job done with a custom JS action: grab the results from the call to A, chunk up the array, and return an array of arrays, like so:

```
const data = workflowContext.actions.API_A_ACTION.outputs.body;
const dataLength = data.length;
const batchedData = [];
const batchSize = 1000;

for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i += batchSize) {
    const batch = data.slice(i, i + batchSize);
    batchedData.push(batch);
}

return batchedData;
```

The the `foreach` action could grab the results from the javascript action, and submit the data in batches.

If there is a better way to do this, though, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with inline code would result in the smallest number of actions, therefore faster/cheaper. An alternative would be to configure workflow B with the `batch` trigger with batch release criteria to be the size of the smaller array you need. Then, in workflow A, send the data to B with the `send to batch` action.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a string function called "chunk" in logic apps. This can be used to split upp arrays in smaller parts. If you combine this with a foreach loop you can process a big array bit by bit. If you want to merge the output from each loop, use the "append to variable" function.